# Angular reactive forms - add group controls array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to build Reactive form like this:

```
public initForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      dosage_id: this.fb.control(this.dosage$.id),
      main: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.setGroups(this.dosage$.groups.data, this.dosage$.products.data);

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
      console.log
    );
  }


  public setGroups(groups: DosageGroup[], products: Product[]): any {
    
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls.main;

    products.forEach(product => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({
        product_id: product.id,
        groups: this.setGroups2(groups, product.id) }));
    });
  }

  private setGroups2(groups: DosageGroup[], id) {

    const arr = new FormArray([]);
     groups.forEach( group => {
       group.products_values.data.map( item => {

         if ( item.id === id ) {
             arr.push(this.fb.group({
               id: group.id,
               kg_SM: item.kg_SM,
               kg_prod:  item.kg_prod,
               ingredients: item.ingredients,
             }));
         }
       });
       console.log('arr return', arr);
       return arr;
     });
  }
```

console log of array shows the groups are build correctly

[image]

but they do not add to form control correctly cause the groups is always NULL

[image]

WHY ??

Comment: You are  returning arr inside forEach loop

Comment: omg, you are so right !  and I had a brain lockdown :P